# how to redirect to same part of a webpage from where the click was initiated

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with PHP codeIgniter currently. 
In a webpage there is a footer which has got a subscription button with a text field. When the user clicks the subscription button with the text field empty the validations are initiated. However the redirection takes me to another part of the page and not to the footer.
I want to return to the footer on redirection. Can anybody suggest generally what needs to be done to get to the same part of the page from where something was initiated.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: simple add a #yourfooterid to the end of the url

Comment: @Wilmer simple but perfect. thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it by using id. 
First add id in your footer div. I am using id name **footerdiv** in below example.

```
<div class="footer" id="footerdiv">

  <!-- Your Subscription Form is here -->

</div>
```

Second when you are redirecting add **#footerdiv** with url
e.g. url#footerdiv

Answer (score 0):

Use your footer id in your redirection address:

```
http://your_address#footer_id
```

This will scroll your page directly to your footer